# Pass multiple parameter using cell button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

**NOTE**: i don't need any suggestion regarding sending data using didselect delegate of UITableview

**myButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface myButton : UIButton
{
    id userData;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* data1;

@end
```

**myButton.m**

```
#import "myButton.h"

@implementation myButton

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

**My custom cell for testCollectionViewCell.h**

```
#import "myButton.h"
@interface testCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell 
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet myButton *serviceFav;
```

**My custom cell for testCollectionViewCell.m**

```
#import "testCollectionViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation testCollectionViewCell
 @synthesize serviceFav;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        //self.serviceFav=[myButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{



}

@end
```

And here is my code for the collection view delegate

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    testCollectionViewCell *cell = [testCollectionViewCell dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"testCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellData = [self.collectionData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.serviceFav.data1 = @"data1"; **//shows error here and kills**

    [cell.serviceFav addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    return cell;
}
```

**//------ THIS IS NOT CALLED ----I WANT TO CALL IT**

```
-(void)touchUpHandler:(myButton*)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (myButton *)sender; //instance of UIButton
    NSLog(@"Data 1 = %@",sender.data1);
}
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question, you meant to say that `fav_action` not called instead of`touchUpHandler`

Comment: edit done please check now

Comment: what is `myButton` here. I assume there is only `cell.btnLike` for button

Comment: check attach link code its a subclass of UIButton

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: its not calling the function, please check and run in your machine

Comment: Posted a sample link in the answer. I just made it now. Check and run in your machine

Comment: I hope you checked that, if it helps kindly accept as a tick

Comment: Its not working in my case -> UItableview->UITableviewCell (contain UICollectionviewCell) the button is in UICollectionviewCell and its not working ?any solution

Comment: Oh cmon man, then make that button in your collection cell and the data source and delegate for CollectionCell is the TableCell. Whats the big deal

Comment: have you rechecked the tags associated in your question, there is only `UITableView`, So I assumed that it is a table, but the things are same for collection too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made a sample with the same process as in the Question and it worked.

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb2k7nzsytxjnl2/tabletest.zip?dl=0

Took a custom Button Class

**MyButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyButton : UIButton

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* data1;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* data2;

@end
```

**MyButton.m**

```
#import "MyButton.h"

@implementation MyButton

@end
```

Make an IBOutlet to your `CustomCell` Class

**CustomTableViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyButton.h"

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyButton *btnLike;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell* cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];

    cell.btnLike.data1 = @"data1";
    cell.btnLike.data2 = @"data2";

    [cell.btnLike addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpHandler:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}

- (void) touchUpHandler:(MyButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Data 1 = %@",sender.data1);
    NSLog(@"Data 2 = %@",sender.data2);

}
@end
```

On clicking on the button in the cell, it goes to the selector method `touchUpHandler` and prints on console

```
2016-10-12 23:14:39.034 tabletest[28414:671128] Data 1 = data1
2016-10-12 23:14:39.035 tabletest[28414:671128] Data 2 = data2
```

Comment: @iphonemaclover Its better if you attach your complete code and upload on dropbox so that I can check

Comment: I want to see where are you providing your datasource for `UICollectionView`